# Autocomplete List not centred below box (Next.js + Material UI)

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete, alignment, next.js13

Im trying to learn Web-Development on my own and a colleague suggested Next.Js/React and I like material UI.

Problem is, that the first thing im using - an autocomplete box - is not doing what I think its supposed to do: The list that appears when you click the box is about 100/200px to the left of where it should be:
[image]

This is my code in my components folder:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import Spacer from "../spacer";
import Header from "../header";

export default function mainDesign() {
  return (
    <>
        <Spacer />
        <Header />
        <Autocomplete
            disablePortal
            id="combo-box-demo"
            options={top100Films}
            sx={{ width: 300, margin:"auto", color:'white'}}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
        />
    </>
  );
}
  

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { label: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { label: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
];
```

Ive tried removing the "margin:auto", but then the list is still to the left of the autocomplete box, just the box is at the left of the page. I defined the body to be about 1200px and there are margins to the rest of both sides, and the list is exactly at the very left of the browser window over those margins outside the 1200px width of the screen. So when I make my browser narrower than that it lines up, but if its bigger I have the problem.

Ive also tried this:

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Autocomplete
                disablePortal
                id="combo-box-demo"
                options={top100Films}
                sx={{ width: 300, margin:"auto", color:'white', display:'flex'}}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
            />
        </div>
```

-> Wrapping it by a div with the styles above, and adding the "display:flex" to the autocomplete "sx" directly. None of these work.

Comment: Your Autocomplete component itself works fine for me.  Problem possibly caused by other css or containers that you are not showing.